# How to use realm on an electron app?

Tags: node.js, realm, electron

```
ERROR in ./~/realm/lib/browser/index.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native' in
'/Users/H/Documents/MyApp/node_modules/realm/lib/browser'

@ ./~/realm/lib/browser/index.js 21:0-45

@ ./~/realm/lib/index.js

@ ./render/routes/tools/Network.js

@ ./render/router.js

@ ./render/index.js

@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9527 webpack/hot/dev-server react-hot-loader/patch webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9527/ webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./render/index.js

Not rewriting GET /dist/bundle.js because the path includes a dot (.) character.
```

I want to use `realm` in an `electron` app, and I used the code below but it doesn't work and the error imformation is above.

```
const Realm = require('realm')
let realm = new Realm({
  schema: [
    {
      name: 'LogItem',
      properties: {
        time: 'date',
        percent: 'double'
      }
    }
  ]
})
realm.write(() => {
  realm.create('Log', {
    time: new Date(),
    percent: 90.00
  })
})
```

Comment: Realm works with Node 4 and Node 6, and React-Native. What platform are you trying to use it with with Electron?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I used Node 6.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you help me?

Comment: unfortunately i do not know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Realm is working on Electron support, but it's not supported currently (which is why you're getting errors). You can keep track of their efforts here: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/818